# Create List of Type customType

Tags: c#, list, types

I am trying to create a list of a custom type that is set at runtime. How is this possible?

Here is my code:

```
Type customType = typeof(string); // or someOtherVariable.GetType();

List<customType> ls = new List<customType>(); // Error: The type or namespace name `customType' could not be found
```

Comment: why not just add string instead of customType?

Comment: This code does not make sense, you seem like you are creating a list of strings.

Comment: In actuality, the type will be set at runtime. For example: Type customType = someOtherVariable.GetType();

Comment: Justin Niessner's answer is, of course, correct, but I would add this: the technique is useful in some cases, but mostly you can find another solution that doesn't require reflection and is just as good (or, rather, better, because it is simpler).  If you can post more detail about *why* you want to do that, you might get suggestions for a better solution to the larger problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to instantiate a generic list of some reflected type, you'll have to use Reflection to do so:

```
var type = typeof(string);

var list = typeof(List<>);
var listOfType = list.MakeGenericType(type);

var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(listOfType);
```

Comment: How can the variable 'instance' used as list, since it's datatype is var?

Comment: @DrRiisTab - `var` isn't a data type. It's merely a shortcut that allows the compiler to set the static type for you. If you want to use `instance` in a list, you'd have to use the Generic overload: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0hcyx2kd(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score -1):

You cannot do this. Generics collections are strongly typed at compile time. You could perhaps emit/codegen a new class and compile it on the fly when needed, but that is a very different problem

Comment: Or, you could use reflection.  (I didn't downvote this answer, but I presume that was the reason someone else did.)